# Node update error

Tags: nodejs

He actualizado mi versión de `Node.js` (de **14.15 a 18.7**) y luego de ello los proyectos que antes levantaban con `npm start` ahora ya no levantan..

Arrojan errores internos. Comparto el error:

> Starting the development server...
>
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
> at module.exports (C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
> at handleParseError (C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
> at C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
> at C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
> at C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
> at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
> at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
>
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
> at module.exports (C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
> at C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
> at C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
> at C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
> at C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
> at context.callback (C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
> at C:\Users\e603158\Documents\GitHub\cid-ui-local-aio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
> opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
> library: 'digital envelope routines',
> reason: 'unsupported',
> code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
> }

Si alguno podría ayudarme que puede estar sucediendo y como se pueda resolver agradecería bastante. Gracias

Comment: Elimina `package-lock.json` y `node-modules`, vuelve a ejecutar `npm install` y prueba nuevamente.